# Question about composition of linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra

{e, f, g} is an orthonormal basis.
Let P1 and P2 be linear operators in 3d Euclidean space such that;

P1(e)=f, P1(f)=e, P1(g)=g
P2(e)=-e, P2(f)=f, P2(g)=g

My question is about the composition of these operators, P = P1 o P2.

P1(P2(e)) = P1(-e)

From this point, can I say, or is it true, that P1(-e) = -P1(e) = -f ?

As P1 (-e) is not defined I am unsure of what exactly to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given two linear maps $P_1,P_2:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ defined on an orthonormal basis $\beta=\{e,f,g\}$ for $\Bbb R^3$ as
\begin{align*}
P_1(e) &= f & P_2(e) &= -e \\
P_1(f) &= e & P_2(f) &= f \\
P_1(g) &= g & P_2(g) &= g
\end{align*}
The composition $P_1\circ P_2:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ is thus defined on $\beta$ as
\begin{align*}
(P_1\circ P_2)(e) & = P_1(P_2(e)) & (P_1\circ P_2)(f) & = P_1(P_2(f)) &(P_1\circ P_2)(g) &= P_1(P_2(g)) \\
&= P_1(-e) & &= P_1(f) & &= P_1(g) \\
&= -P_1(e) & &= e & &= g \\
&= -f
\end{align*}
The point is that linear maps always satisfy the equality $T(\lambda v)=\lambda T(v)$ for scalars $\lambda$ and vectors $v$. In this case $P_1(-e)=-P_1(e)$.

Also note that the assumption that $\beta$ is an orthonormal basis is not used in these computations.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is right. $P_1(-e) = -P_1(e)$ because $P_1$ is a linear operator.

A linear operator T satisfies $T(\lambda v) = \lambda v$ for vector v and $\lambda$ scalar